# How do I iterate through a loop 1 by 1 removing a classList value each time an event is fired?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a function attached to a scroll-down event which adds a class one by one to an array of items. I want to now make a function that does the opposite and attach it to a scroll up event. Any help will be met with great praise!

I made a function that when the scroll up event is fired it removes all the classes from the array, but I want to remove them one by one.

```
var slide = document.querySelectorAll('div.about-slide');
```

This is the function im using to add the classes to the elements one by one

```
function addOnScroll() {
    for  ( var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++){
        if(slide[i].classList.contains('scroll')){
            continue;
        }else{
            slide[i].classList.add('scroll');
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

This is fired on a scroll up event, it removes all the added class from the code above. But I want it to remove the classes one by one.

```
function removeOnScroll() {
  for  ( var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++){

    slide[i].classList.remove('scroll')

  }
};
```

The mouse scroll event I'm using.

```
    function onDocumentMouseScroll( event ) {
    console.log(event);

        if( Date.now() - lastMouseWheelStep > 600 ) {

            lastMouseWheelStep = Date.now();

            var delta = event.detail || -event.wheelDelta;
            if( delta > 0 ) {
                navigateNext();
                addOnScroll();
                moveBackground();


            }

            else if( delta < 0 ) {
                navigatePrev();
                removeOnScroll();
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean *one by one*? You might want to to google `intersectionObserver`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I mean I want to add and then remove the class 'scroll' depending on which direction the user is scrolling. I have 4 items that have the 'scroll' class added them when the user scrolling the mouse scrolls down. I want to remove the class scroll when the user is scrolling up. Let me know if you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, why not do the opposite of what you do on the scroll down ?

```js
function addOnScroll() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
    if (slide[i].classList.contains('scroll')) {
      continue;
    } else {
      slide[i].classList.add('scroll');
      break;
    }
  }
};

function removeOnScroll() {
  for (var i = slide.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (!slide[i].classList.contains('scroll')) {
      continue;
    } else {
      slide[i].classList.remove('scroll');
      break;
    }
  }
};
```

---

However, to simplify your code you could just do a new selection each time

```js
function addOnScroll() {
  var next = document.querySelector('div.about-slide:not(.scroll)');
  if (next)
    next.classList.add('scroll');
};

function removeOnScroll() {
  var all = document.querySelectorAll('div.about-slide.scroll'),
      last = all[all.length - 1]

  if (last)
    last.classList.remove('scroll');
};
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully you are a legend! I still have a lot to learn hope you have a great summer buddy. Can't stress the fact of how much of a legend you are though!

Answer (score 0):

You can improve below code and it will help updating class one by one [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fvgb82mc/1/).

```
// For Chrome
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', mouseWheelEvent);
// For Firefox
window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', mouseWheelEvent);

function mouseWheelEvent(e) {
  var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("about-slide");
  var bScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  for (var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
    var sHeight = slide[i].offsetHeight;
    var offsets = slide[i].offsetTop;
    if (bScroll > offsets && bScroll < offsets + sHeight) {
      slide[i].classList.add('scroll');
    } else {
      slide[i].classList.remove('scroll');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and reply you're an angel, I understand your code but it's a full-screen page with no overscroll so this isn't working.